# Activity state android

Tags: android, android-activity, state

I have a couple of quick question about the variable/state of an activity in android. When you access to the options of that activity (Preferences) and you come back to activity, that activity realize "onResume()" isnt it?

And another question: when one activity is "onPause()" state, does its variables die? Or does it keep the state?

Thanks

Comment: The first question is absolutely unclear, rephrase it please...

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult question because the Android OS decides when those variables are detroyed.  It's better defined in the Android Application Lifecycle.. variables could be lost immediatley after onPause or not at all. (thus it's no onPause()'s doing).  One would think it's all done OnDestroy() but that's not the case either.. Android could kill all variables w/o OnDestor ever being called.  So in general it's best to save state using onSaveInstanceState and restore it using onRestoreInstanceState.